# showing tooltips all the time in chartjs 2.4 not working

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to show the tooltips for chartjs all the time. I copied this code directly from https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1861, but it's still not working. I get the error message "Chart.Tooltip.positioners[opts.position] is not a function".

Can anyone help, please? It's probably one little thing...

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeRender: function (chart) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // create an array of tooltips
            // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
            chart.pluginTooltips = [];
            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                    chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                        _chart: chart.chart,
                        _chartInstance: chart,
                        _data: chart.data,
                        _options: chart.options,
                        _active: [sector]
                    }, chart));
                });
            });

            // turn off normal tooltips
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    },
    afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
            if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                if (easing !== 1)
                    return;
                chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
            }

            // turn on tooltips
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
            Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                tooltip.initialize();
                tooltip.update();
                // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                tooltip.pivot();
                tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
            });
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    }
});


        //var ctx = document.getElementById("chrtWhoPays").getContext("2d");
        //var piechart = new Chart(ctx, config);

      var ctx = document.getElementById("chrtWhoPays");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ["Payer1", "Payer2", "Payer3", "Payer4", "Payer5", "Payer6"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [51.9, 22.3, 15.7, 7.9, 0.6, 1.6],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#333',
                    '#547b84',
                    '#2faea9',
                    '#a2d5ab',
                    '#433c3b',
                    '#e4efc1'
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            showAllTooltips: true

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to be that you are not using the most updated version of the plugin service (there is a comment with an updated version after someone stated it broke in 2.1.6)

Use the most up to date version and you should be fine, here is their example with your data

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // create an array of tooltips
      // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });

      // turn off normal tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }

      // turn on tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Payer1", "Payer2", "Payer3", "Payer4", "Payer5", "Payer6"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [51.9, 22.3, 15.7, 7.9, 0.6, 1.6],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#333',
        '#547b84',
        '#2faea9',
        '#a2d5ab',
        '#433c3b',
        '#e4efc1'
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    showAllTooltips: true

  }
});

var data = {
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
  }]
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```